# Uploadify 3 - Send Custom Error from upload.php back to client

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I'm trying to upload some files via Uploadify v3 (Flash version). The upload.php validates each file, e.g. for minimum image dimension etc. I can't seem to find a way to tell the javascript, that there is an error with the processed file.

Here's some code - upload.php:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)) {
    $size = getimagesize($targetFile);
    if($size['0'] >= 100) {
        //modify, copy, blablah
        echo "successful";
    } else {
        echo "error2"; //the width of the file is too small
        unlink($targetFile);
        die();
    }
} else {
    echo "error1"; //fail while copying
    die();
}
```

Every single time the script runs, I catch the output with the `onUploadSuccess`-event:

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                        console.log(file+" ----- "+data+" ----- "+response);
                    }
```

The response is `true` with any file, that gets uploaded - whether php returns nothing, a string (number, false, "error1"), an int (0, 1, 2, ...) or whatever.

How can I submit an error from php back to the client?!

*Edit*: The variable `data` shows the echoed string correct, but the upload-act/response is `true`/successful...

Comment: The thing is, if your server responds with a code `200`, which it will do if there's no 404's or internal server errors, jquery thinks that the request was successfull.

Comment: So how should I handle the situation? Send fake HTTP-Codes which the javascript will process?

Comment: Don't try to change how the web works, adjust your problem around it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your server doesn't return with an error code (`404,500, etc`), jQuery thinks that your request was succesful. If you want to return an error from the server side, like "image too big", you've to catch that data and do something to it on client side.

So, assuming your request looks similar to jQuery `$.ajax`, (and it does), here's something to get you started.

So here's how you could do it if you would be using `$.ajax` (which is a regular jQuery function)

```
$.ajax({
   url:"url.php",
   data:data,
   success:function(return_data){
       if(return_data == "Your custom error from server"){
        // do something
       }
   }
});
```

And here's how you could do it in your case (haven't used uploadify myself)

I don't know the contents of `file`, `data` and `response` but it should be similar.

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
   console.log(file+" ----- "+data+" ----- "+response);
   if(data == "Your error?"){
     somefunction();
   }

   if(response == "Your error?"){
     somefunction();
    }

 }
```

Comment: The upload process is done by a swf file, and not by a "normal" ajax function. The swf file somehow loads the php file and executes it. Jquery gets the responses by the swf file (i guess). Firebug doenst show requests in console- and networktab. I guess I'll let jquery increase an int for every succssfull `data`-string and build anything after on the basis of the int - it seems to be the easiest way for me at the moment...

Comment: @MukMuk can't you validate the file in the flash configuration file?

Comment: the docs state that you just include the swf file and the magic happens. no source, no further documentation about that. As I said before, I just count a variable for every successfull data-output. For now it works that way :)